Styling of TOC, List of Figures, List of Tables,... heading
I am using the memoir class and the titlesec package to style my chapter & section headings. However these don't seem to be used for the headings of the Table of Contents, the List of Figures etc. These remain with the default styling.
The chapter styling I defined: 
The styling of the ToC heading: 
Any information that I was able to find so far, have been on how to style the toc items, which I don't want to do.
I am compiling the document with latexmk and xelatex if anyone can show me or hint me in the direction of how I can change the formatting of the toc heading.
Thank you in advance!
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=18mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  pdftex,
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thechapter\hspace{4pt}\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart.\arabic{chapter}}

\titleformat
  {\chapter}
  [hang]
  {\centering\fontsize{36pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
  {\thechapter\hspace{12pt}}
  {0pt}
  {}
  [{\vspace{4pt}\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}

\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Listings}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}

\backmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}


Not an answer, just as note: memoir has its own user interface to configure chapters, table of contents, etc. See, e.g. section 6.5 and section 9.2 of the user manual.

\chapter and \chapter* (used byt the TOC etc.) have different headings, typically provided by \@makechapterhead and \@makeschapterhead.
